# My Wordpress plugins folder was hacked by placing a file that sent out spam emails how to I prevent that from happening?

Tags: security, wordpress, spam-prevention

Hackers placed a file named trimite.php in our Wordpress plugins folder that sent out spam emails.  We have a hardware firewall.  We only have one Wordpress login and just a couple of plug-ins.  We have Wordfence and Security Ninja Lite installed also and usually try to keep things up to date.

Any advice would be very helpful, this email hack has stopped a lot of servers from accepting emails from us and that isn't good because in order to register on our website we send a confirmation email.

Comment: Your "hardware firewall" doesn't help much unless you're hosting the site within your own network, which I assume you aren't.

Answer (score 1):

This question is too broad to give any real answer, but check some of the usual suspects:

- TimThumb in plugins or the theme
- Weak usernames and/or passwords (the admin user should not be called
  "admin")
- A theme downloaded from some random website or, even worse, from a
  site that explicitly deals in pirated themes.

Comment: Don't use Tim Thumb, changed user names, passwords consistently and created our own theme.  We've kept plug-ins to a minimum and up-to-date, we use Wordfence and Security Ninja Lite but was wondering if we are missing some security plug-in or feature?  Or is there something else we should be doing?

Comment: Did you use a base theme to create your custom theme? What plugins are you using? Are you using shared hosting or some other environment where it's possible that a vulnerability in another site could have let the attackers in? Check for new, unknown admin users in the users table as well.